# Updating a partial form with Ajax and have the results go to the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/working-with-html-beginform-and-ajax-beginform-in-mvc-3/

Here is my (abbreviated) model (not that it's important)

```
 public class Iro : EntityBase
    {
        public int ReportYear { get; set; }
        public Guid DcmDataCallId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
...snip...
    }
```

and my viewmodel (not that it's important either):

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int SelectedIro { get; set; }
    public string IroName { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> IroNames { get; set; }
    public List<IroViewModel> Iros { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the main view:

```
@model Doi.IroAnnualSurvey.ViewModels.HomeViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("I", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "Hello" }))
{
<div class="control-label">
    <table class="table-bordered">
            @foreach (Doi.IroAnnualSurvey.ViewModels.IroViewModel iroViewModel in Model.Iros)
            {
                <tr class="row"><td style ="padding: 15px">@iroViewModel.FEIN</td><td style="width: 300px">@iroViewModel.IroName</td><td><input type="button" id="Iro_@iroViewModel.IroEntityNumber.ToString()" name="@iroViewModel.FEIN" value="Select" text="Change" /></td></tr>
            }
    </table>
</div>

<div class="row">
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SelectedIro)
</div>
}
<div id="ClientInformation">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("Member", Model.Iros.ElementAt(0));}
</div>
<div id="Hello"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(this).click(function () {
            var controlId = this.activeElement.id.toLowerCase();
            if (controlId.indexOf('iro_') == 0) {
                $("#ClientInformation").load("/home/Member?EntityNumber=" + controlId.substr(4) + "&Dummy=" + Math.round(Math.random() * 10000));
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And here's the partial view:

```
    @model Doi.IroAnnualSurvey.Models.Iro

    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateIroContact", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "updateresult" }))
{
    Layout = "";
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
<table>
    <tr><td>Prefix:</td><td>@Model.ContactNamePrefix</td></tr>
    <tr><td>First Name:</td><td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ContactFirstName)</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Middle Name:</td><td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ContactMiddleName)</td></tr>
     ... snip ...
    <tr><td>Email:</td><td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.BusinessEmail)</td></tr>
</table>
<div class="btn-block"><button>Update</button></div>
<div id="updateresult"></div>
}
```

And finally, the action in the controller:

```
 public ActionResult UpdateIroContact(Iro iro)
    {
        Iro dbIro = db.Iroes.Find(iro.Id);
        dbIro.ContactFirstName = iro.ContactFirstName;
        dbIro.ContactJobTitle = iro.ContactJobTitle;
        ... snip ...
        db.Entry(dbIro).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Content("Contact information updated");
    }
```

As far as I can tell, that's fundamentally the same as in the article, except that I'm updating from the partial view and not the main view.  What happens is when you click the update button (on the partial view) it calls the UpdateIroContact action in the Home controller (like it's supposed to) and the database gets updated but the string "Contact information updated" gets returned to a separate blank page instead of just updating the `<div>` like I expect.  Reading that post in the link above, that's the behavior he got when he used `Html.BeginForm()`, but not when he used `Ajax.BeginForm()`.

So the question is what's different?  What did I do wrong?  (BTW, the Ajax.BeginForm() in the main view is there to ensure that the right form is being submitted.)

Comment: Have you included the relevant scripts - `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`?

Answer (score 0):

Stephen was correct.  I needed to install Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax, add

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryunobtrusive").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax*"));
```

to Bundle.Config.cs and

```
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryunobtrusive")
```

to my _Layout.shtml